# Mongoose unique value per day

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Im trying to configure mongoose schema unique param. I need to allow write to DB no more than one unique author per one day period. 
Schema.index( { author: 1, created: 1  } , { unique: true} ) not works, here I can't enter time period.

What better way to decide this case?

```
const Report = new Schema({
  author: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'DiscordUserList',
    required: true
  },
  reports: [{ reportNum: { type: Number }, text: { type: String }, date: { type: Date, default: Date.now } }],
  questionsDone: [{ questionNum: { type: Number }, done: { type: Boolean }, date: { type: Date, default: Date.now } }],
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
}, { strict: false })
Report.plugin(mongoosePaginate)



const reportListSchema = mongoose.model('ReportList', Report)


module.exports = reportListSchema
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do an update operation with **[`$setOnInsert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/)** and `upsert` option i.e if the [`update()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) with `upsert: true` had found a matching document, then MongoDB performs an update, applying the **[`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set)** operation but ignoring the **[`$setOnInsert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/)** operation. Thus your typical update would be as follows:

```
import moment from 'moment'

const start = moment().startOf('day').toDate() // set to 12:00 am today
const end = moment().endOf('day').toDate() // set to 23:59 pm today
ReportList.findOneAndUpdate(
    { 
        'author': author_id, 
        'created': { '$gte': start, '$lte': end }
    },
    {
        '$set': { 'author': author_id },
        '$setOnInsert': { 'created': moment().toDate() }
    },
    { 'upsert': true, 'new': true },
    (err, report) => {
        console.log(report)
    }
)
```

or using the [`setDefaultsOnInsert`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) option which when this and `upsert` are true, mongoose will apply the defaults specified in the model's schema if a new document is created:

```
ReportList.findOneAndUpdate(
    { 
        'author': author_id, 
        'created': { '$gte': start, '$lte': end }
    },
    { '$set': { 'author': author_id } },
    { 
        'upsert': true, 
        'new': true, 
        'setDefaultsOnInsert': true 
    },
    (err, report) => {
        console.log(report)
    }
)
```